# PHP: Autocomplete inputs when MySQL table element selected

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm building a simple app to send confirmation emails. I have a MySQL table with 4 columns: `id`, `user_email`, `user_name` and `user_track`. The form consists of a `selectbox` that shows all the `user_email` stored and two text `inputs` that should be autocompleted when an email is selected.
I have tried the following, but it just `echo`'s all the entries for `user_track` and `user_name`.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, user_email, user_name, user_track FROM demo_data ORDER BY id DESC";
$option = '';
$artist = '';
$track = '';
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['user_email'].'">'.$row['user_email'].'</option>';
    $track .= '<input type="text" name="track" required value = "'.$row['user_track'].'">';
    $artist .= '<input type="text" name="artist" required value = "'.$row['user_name'].'">';
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Admin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <h1>Accepted demo</h1>
<form action="demo.php" method="post">
 <select name="select"> 
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select><br><br>
<?php echo $track; ?><br><br>
<?php echo $artist; ?><br><br>
<input type="date" name="date" placeholder="Release Date" required>
<br><br>
<input style="margin-top:10px;" class="btn" type="submit" value="Send email">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: look your query.... you are asking for every row of `user_track` and `user_name`

Comment: @xmastertje Yes, that's the problem I saw. How can I target only the row of the selected email?

Comment: @ArnauJiménez use the `where` clause in your query. `where  user_email = selected user_email`

Comment: use where statement something like `WHERE id = '2'`

Comment: @ArnauJiménez check the bellow answer

Answer (score 0):

update **From**

```
$sql = "SELECT id, user_email, user_name, user_track FROM demo_data ORDER BY id DESC";
```

**To**

```
$sql = "SELECT id, user_email, user_name, user_track FROM demo_data WHERE user_email='".$_POST['selected_user_email']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

where selected_user_email is the name of input field that is being posted

Comment: The error log throws the following error: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: user_email

Comment: @ArnauJiménez $`user_email` = `$_POST['select'` before the statement

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile is correct, kindly assign $user_email your email address before query.

Comment: @UmairIftikhar -  Yes, I know, but it throws the error above.

Comment: @ArnauJiménez Updated my answer, selected_user_email is the name of the input field, you can change it according to your field name

Comment: @UmairIftikhar Thanks for your effort, but still no success. I have tried targeting the `select` name and the `option` name, but it still says Undefined Index. 
Could it be because the form is inside the php file or maybe I have to put an `if(asset($_POST['select']))` ? I don't know...